# Why aren't my pointers to integer arrays working?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Here is the problem: http://cps125.scs.ryerson.ca/labs/homework8.gif

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void tenfold(int (*array1)[9], int (*array2)[9])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if ((*array1)[i] > 0) {
            (*array2)[i] = 10 * (*array1)[i];
        } else {
            (*array2)[i] = (*array1)[i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int array1[9] = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, -8, -9, 1, 2 }, array2[9], i;

    tenfold(&array1, &array2);

    for (i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%lf ", array2[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

44100667367791664000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000.000000 441006673677917200000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 4410066736779177
60000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000.000000 4410066736779183200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 44100667367791888000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000
44100691391845304000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000.000000 441006913918452980000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 4410066736779155
20000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000.000000 4410066736779160800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is at least a problem here:

```
printf("%lf ", array2[i]);
```

`%lf` literally means "long float", however you want to print integers:

```
printf("%i\n", array2[i]);
```

Also remember that printf waits for `\n` to flush.

EDIT: As newacct pointed out, `%f` and `%lf` are both `double` in the end, since varargs promote `float` to `double`.

Comment: @user1251385 always compiler with `-Wall` option

Comment: As said above, compiling with `-W -Wall -Werror` will prevent this kind of mistakes from happening. Reading the man too!

Comment: and in `printf`, `%lf` is the same as `%f` (both are `double`)

Answer (score 0):

No need to add asterisk in the definition of input array in the function `tenfold`

just define it as following

```
void tenfold(int array1[9], int array2[9])
```

And remove the asterisk `*` when using `array1` and `array2` into the function `tenfold`

```
void tenfold(int array1[9], int array2[9])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if ((array1)[i] > 0) {
            (array2)[i] = 10 * (array1)[i];
        } else {
            (array2)[i] = (array1)[i];
        }
    }
}
```

and when you call the `tenfold` function in the `main`:

```
tenfold(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

"%lf " is the format for a float, not an int.